# minimum of sum of squared weights

Tags: calculus

It seems from my simulation results that *sum of squared weights*
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{N}W_{i}^{2}\,,\quad\mbox{with the constrain}\quad
\sum_{i = 1}^{N}W_{i} = 1
$$
has a minimum when all weights are equal $W_{i} = 1/N$.

Is there a theorem that confirms or denies this ?. Thanks, Alec.

Comment: Please use this:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to learn how we format things on math stack exchange.

Comment: See [Root-Mean Square-Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean-Harmonic mean Inequality](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) with emphasis on the first two.

Comment: Check my edition such that you start to grasp $\texttt{MathJax}$ and/or $\LaTeX$ !!!. There is a $\LaTeX$-[MSE MatJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of showing this.

One way is to note that $f(x) = \sum_k x_k^2$ is convex and so is the
set $C= \{x | \sum_k x_k = 1 \}$.

Then, given some $x \in C$, let $\bar{x} = { 1\over n} (x_1+\cdots+ x_n)$, and then note that $(\bar{x},...,\bar{x}) \in C$, since the set $C$ is invariant
under permutations of the indices.

Furthermore, $f((\bar{x},...,\bar{x})) \le {1 \over n} (f((x_1,...,x_n))+ f((x_2,x_3,...,x_n,x_1))+ \cdots + f((x_n,x_1,...,x_{n-1})))$.

Hence we can restrict our search for a minimum to points of the form
$t(1,....,1)$, and hence the problem becomes
$\min \{ n t^2 | n t = 1 \}$ from which we can read off the solution $t = {1 \over n}$.

Hence the point ${1 \over n} (1,...,1)$ is **a** minimiser. Now we note that
$f$ is strictly convex, hence it follows that the unique solution is
${1 \over n} (1,...,1)$.